# How to find out length of bisector?

Tags: triangles

I found this challenge online but can't solve it.

I have a triangle C is 90 degrees. The bisector of A cuts BC into 5 and 3, how do i find out how long the bisector is?

[image]

Comment: Use the [Angle Bisector Theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Angle_Bisector_Theorem).

Comment: Do you know the length of $AB$ or $AC$ ?

Comment: No, I don't. @MattiP.

Comment: When you say the bisector of $A$ cuts $BC$ into $5$ and $3$, do you mean it cuts $BC$ in the ratio $5:3$, or do you mean $BC$ is cut in two pieces whose lengths are literally $5$ and $3$, so that the length of $BC$ must be $5 + 3 = 8$?

Comment: Yes, the lengths are 5 and 3. @MattiP.

Comment: @Mohammedhamed46534 Which one is 5 and which one is 3?

Comment: @jjagmath the part nearer B must be larger than the part nearer C -  a property of the tangent function

Comment: How do i solve this? @Henry

Comment: How do i solve this? @MattiP.

Comment: I think we should still have some length ... If we only fix the lengths between $B$ and $C$, we can still "scale" the picture horizontally and we can pull $A$ as far as we want! And we would still maintain the $5:3$ ratio ...

Comment: You think there is no solution? @MattiP.

Comment: @MattiP. No - There is only one possible length of $AC$ which satisfies the conditions.  Call this $s$ and you can use player3236's hint to find it: $AB=\sqrt{s^2+8^2} = \frac53s$.  Then you can find the length of the bisector

Comment: I don't know how? @MattiP.

Comment: @Henry Okay. I think I missed something then.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $AD$ bisects $\angle BAC$. From the angle bisector theorem, we have
$$\frac{BD}{DC} = \frac{AB}{AC} = \frac{5}{3}$$

Letting $l(AB) = 5x$ and $l(AC) = 3x$, by Pythagoras thoerem,
$$25x^2 = 64 + 9x^2$$
$$\implies 16x^2 = 64$$
$$\implies x = 2$$

Therefore $l(AC) = 6$, $l(DC) = 3$, now we use Pythagoras theorem again to compute $l(AD)$,
$$l(AD) = \sqrt{36+9} = \sqrt{45} = 3\sqrt{5}$$

Comment: Nope, $\sqrt{AC^2+CD^2}$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, silly me!

Answer (score 1):

From the given, $$\frac{\tan2\alpha}{\tan\alpha}=\frac{5+3}3,$$

and we are looking for the value of

$$\frac3{\sin\alpha}.$$

> $$\tan\alpha=\frac12\to\sin\alpha=\frac1{\sqrt5},\\3\sqrt5.$$

Comment: I like this approach